# how to access prototype functions in console

Tags: javascript, window

I created a javascript and added it to a page like this:

```
(function (window, google, List){
var myfunction = (function(){}
myfunction.prototype = {
hint: function(){alert('a good advise');}
})
}(window, google, List))
```

I added the needed js files, and it works! it will show the result after loading when instatination id like

```
var myfancything = myfunction.create();
```

I am getting the result after page load.
BUT! I would expect that if i then open the console and type

```
myfancything.hint();
```

I would see the alert.
I know I was able to do that the other day, but I don't know how I achieved it!

so I would like to use the prototypes in the browser console, can you guys give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: `myfunction` is a local variable inside the IIFE. It's not accessible outside that scope.

Comment: make `myfunction` a property of `window`.

Comment: so you mean if i would
    window.mystuf = myfunction;
it would be accesible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function declared inside another function is not accessible from the outside by default :

```js
f();

try {
  g("u");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

function f () {
  g("f");
  function g (caller) {
    console.log(caller, "called g");
  }
}
```

If you want the inner function to be public, you have to declare it explicitely :

```js
f();

try {
  g("u");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

function f () {
  g("f");
  window.g = g;
  function g (caller) {
    console.log(caller, "called g");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared `myfunction` as a local variable inside the IIFE, it's not accessible outside that scope. Get rid of the IIFE if you want to make it global, or assign to `window.myfunction`.